# Is multithreaded large-scale synchronous I/O multiplexing using select() possible?

Tags: python, c, io

I know I don't need multiple threads for this, but I like to know if multithreading is possible?

I checked internet and people suggest there is no need for multi threading.

Comment: Why did you tag the question with two different programming languages? Does your question apply to Python or to C? Or does it apply to both?

Comment: it is python, but select() is C